# pyodbc: queries containing PIVOT

Tags: python, oracle, pivot, pyodbc

I have problems with oracle queries containing a PIVOT (Oracle) statement!

I have no problems getting data from a table but if the Query contains a pivot statement I get the error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1440, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?
Thanx in advance :)

My code:

```
import pyodbc
from pandas import read_sql_query

dbInst = XXX
schema = YYY
passwd = ZZZ

connString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=" +  dbInst + ';Uid=' + schema + ';Pwd=' + passwd + ";"

sqlWorks = """
select 'A' as  state, 1 as value from dual
"""

sqlDoesNotWork = """
With T As 
(
  select 'A' as  state, 1 as value from dual
)
Select *
From T
Pivot
(
  Sum(Value)
  For State In ('A' As States)
)
"""

conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
data = read_sql_query(sqlWorks, conn)
print data

data2 = read_sql_query(sqlDoesNotWork, conn)
print data2
```

Comment: Give a try using "states" instead of "*" in select.

Comment: Unfortunately same result :(